# Menu gone in DotNetNuke 4.5.5 on IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, dotnetnuke, internet-explorer-10

I have a site that is running DotNetNuke 4.5.5. Users who use IE10 can't see the site main menu. Any clue why this happening, and where to look for solutions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you are using **SolPartMenu** which is not compatible with IE10. Besides the main menu, containers' action menus are also not visible.

I recommend upgrading to [DDRMenu](http://dnnddrmenu.codeplex.com/releases/view/70987), which has been the default navigation provider since DNN 6. There is an install package available for DNN 4.5.0 and above, so you don't have to upgrade DotNetNuke just because of the menu.

DDRMenu provides a simple way to upgrade your SolPartMenu skins and containers, using a compatibility template, which supports many, but not all SolPartMenu properties.

To upgrade a SolPart menu, edit your skin's ASCX files and replace:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="..." src="~/Admin/Skins/SolPartMenu.ascx" %>
```

with

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="..." src="~/DesktopModules/DDRMenu/SolPartMenu.ascx" %>
```

Upgrading a container is a similar process, replace:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="..." Src="~/Admin/Containers/SolPartActions.ascx" %>
```

with

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="..." Src=""~/DesktopModules/DDRMenu/Actions.ascx"" %>
```

#### See also:

[DDRMenu user guide](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/DDRMenu-user-guide.aspx)

Comment: Nice! Quick fix for an old DNN site.

Answer (score 4):

Ii might be a bit late, but I came across this at a customer and I solved the issue by changing the SPMenuCaps.config (\controls\SolpartMenu). I add  under the Renders Uplevel. Now my file looks like this and it works with ie11:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<capabilities> 
    <functionality nm="UpLevel" desc="Renders Uplevel">
        <supports>
            <browser nm="IE" minversion="4" />
            <browser nm="Netscape" minversion="5" />
            <browser nm="Gecko" minversion="1" />
            <browser nm="Opera" minversion="7" />
            <browser contains="Konqueror" />
            <browser contains="Safari" />
            <browser contains="FireFox" />
      <browser contains="Camino" />
      <browser contains="Mozilla" />
        </supports>
        <excludes>
        </excludes>
    </functionality>
    <functionality nm="XMLParsing" desc="Client Side XML Parsing">
        <supports>
            <browser nm="IE" minversion="4" />
            <browser nm="Netscape" minversion="5" />
            <browser nm="Gecko" minversion="1" />
            <browser contains="FireFox" />
      <browser contains="Camino" />
        </supports>
        <excludes>
            <browser contains="Konqueror" />
            <browser contains="Mac" />
            <browser contains="Windows CE" />
        </excludes>
    </functionality>
    <functionality nm="XMLDataIslands" desc="XML DataIslands supported (allows caching)">
        <supports>
            <browser nm="IE" minversion="5" />
        </supports>
        <excludes>
            <browser contains="Mac" />
            <browser contains="Windows CE" />
        </excludes>
    </functionality>
    <functionality nm="Transitions" desc="Menu Effects Transitions">
        <supports>
            <browser nm="IE" minversion="5" />
        </supports>
        <excludes>
            <browser contains="Mac" />
        </excludes>
    </functionality>
</capabilities>
```

Comment: In case it isn't obvious to others, the fix is to add a <browser contains="Mozilla" /> line to the "UpLevel" supports section. Adding this line to the "XMLParsing" supports section helps too. The menu then recognizes anything visiting with a user-agent string containing "Mozilla" as a client that can render the the Javascript menu.

Comment: Big +1 here.  Adding <browser contains="Mozilla" /> to XMLParsing didn't work for me, by the way (in fact it broke Chrome somehow).  I actually had to add it to the "excludes" section of XMLParsing and XMLDataIslands instead.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem and everyone seemed to think upgrading to a more recent version of DNN was the solution.  In my case I inherited an old server (Windows 2003 old) and the solution was in the Server configuration not DNN.  It seems there was a problem in .NET 2.0 and 4.0 where the browser definitions did not include IE 10 this caused _doPostBack to fail near universally on DNN 4+ - DNN6?

The solution can be found in this HotFix:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088

Or in the Reliability Update 2 for .Net 4.0:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600217

Don't forget you can uninstall a Hotfix with the parameter "/uninstall" should something go wrong.

Goodluck!